# When launching ddms from the cli OS X (10.7.3) I get an error: "Failed to get the adb version...."

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, ddms

When launching DDMS from the command line in Lion (10.7.3) I get the following error:

```
E/adb: Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "/Users/stevieo/android-sdk-macosx/tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory
```

This makes sense to me because adb is actually in: /Users/stevieo/android-sdks/platform-tools

How can I modify this path so that ddms will launch on my system?

I have looked into the ddms file itself, but cannot decipher its intent.

One note, I do NOT have this issue on Snow Leopard (10.6.8)....

TIA for any thoughts or assistance.

Regards,

Steve O'Sullivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into your tools directory where you launched `ddms`, you will see the `adb_has_moved.txt` which says:

> The adb tool has moved to platform-tools/
>
> If you don't see this directory in your SDK,
>   launch the SDK and AVD Manager (execute the android tool)
>   and install "Android SDK Platform-tools"
>
> Please also update your PATH environment variable to
>   include the platform-tools/ directory, so you can
>   execute adb from any location.

To solve this, I would change your `~/.bash_profile` to have a line like:

```
# --- add Android platform-tools directory
PATH=~/android-sdks/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH
```

Make sure to open up a new Terminal window so it will reload `~/.bash_profile`

Note that a possible reason why it is working on your 10.6.8 installation is that you may have an older version of the Android SDK, where adb was in still in the tools directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying from eclipse,

Please make sure to create a adb link in /usr/bin/ directory which should solve the problem:

Ex: **ln -s /Users//android-sdks/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb**

**Note:** logging as sudo/root may be required